# return value 0 instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
for (var i = 0; i < memberGroup.length; i++) {
  subMemberType.push(memberGroup[i]["membershipType"])
}

var subMemTypeCount = [];
while (true) {
  subMemberType.forEach(element => {
    subMemTypeCount[element] = (subMemTypeCount[element] || 0) + 1;
  });

  console.log("\t\truby: " + subMemTypeCount["Ruby"]);
  console.log("\t\tgold: " + subMemTypeCount["Gold"]);
  console.log("\t\tplatinum: " + subMemTypeCount["Platinum"]);
  console.log("\t\tdiamond: " + subMemTypeCount["Diamond"]);
  break;
}
```

```
Output:
                ruby: 2
                gold: 2
                platinum: undefined
                diamond: 1
```

What I am trying to achieve is to print out each membership type "ruby", "gold", "platinum", & "diamond".

I used a `forEach` to loop through the array `subMemberType` to count the number of duplicated membership type.

`memberGroup[i]["membershipType"]` is an 2D array, with a constructor `membershipType`.

My problem is that when I pushed `memberGroup[i]["membershipType"]` to array `subMemberType`, there wasn't the "platinum" membership type. Hence, when I loop through the array using for each to find the duplicated membership type, it returns as `undefined`. However, I would like it to return "0" instead of "undefined". Is there anyway I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `subMemTypeCount` to an empty array (which should have been an object), set it to an object containing those for properties with the value `0`. Then you can also reduce the body of the `.forEach()` to `subMemTypeCount[element]++`.

As an aside: a while-loop that loops unconditionally and breaks unconditionally after the first iteration, is fully redundant.

```js
const subMemberType = ['Ruby', 'Diamond', 'Ruby', 'Gold', 'Gold'];

var subMemTypeCount = {'Ruby': 0, 'Gold': 0, 'Platinum': 0, 'Diamond': 0};
subMemberType.forEach(element => {
  subMemTypeCount[element]++;
});

console.log("\t\truby: " + subMemTypeCount["Ruby"]);
console.log("\t\tgold: " + subMemTypeCount["Gold"]);
console.log("\t\tplatinum: " + subMemTypeCount["Platinum"]);
console.log("\t\tdiamond: " + subMemTypeCount["Diamond"]);
```

Alternatively you can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator), or the [Logical OR (`||`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) in case the nullish coalescing operator isn't supported.

```js
const subMemberType = ['Ruby', 'Diamond', 'Ruby', 'Gold', 'Gold'];

var subMemTypeCount = {};
subMemberType.forEach(element => {
  subMemTypeCount[element] = (subMemTypeCount[element] || 0) + 1;
});

console.log("\t\truby: " + (subMemTypeCount["Ruby"] ?? 0));
console.log("\t\tgold: " + (subMemTypeCount["Gold"] ?? 0));
console.log("\t\tplatinum: " + (subMemTypeCount["Platinum"] ?? 0));
console.log("\t\tdiamond: " + (subMemTypeCount["Diamond"] ?? 0));
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing some trouble with you answer

Comment: After running your code once, it give me the output that I want. However, after running it twice or more, it just kepts on adding the existing value with the current output value. I.e after running it once, the number of ruby is 2 which is right. However, after running it twice, the number of ruby has increased to 4 which is wrong.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: @John Make sure to set those values back to `0` before you run this code. So if you are using the first sample, set `subMemTypeCount = {'Ruby': 0, 'Gold': 0, 'Platinum': 0, 'Diamond': 0};` or if you run the second sample, set `subMemTypeCount = {}`. You can also put it in a separate function so that `subMemTypeCount` is a local variable therefor is reset with every function call. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/q2kLzog1/1/

Comment: Sorry I should make clear that I am using Visual Studio Code so there isnt any button

Comment: @John The button is just there to show that it works. The principal remains the same. Have it is a separate function so that every time that function is executed, it creates a new object with those values initially set to 0.

Comment: What if I can to make the function more dynamic in the sense that, there wouldnt be any hard coding required to change then membershiptype if I ever change it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle undefined elements in one line, you can try something like:

```
console.log ("\t\tplatinum: " + (subMemTypeCount["Platinum"])?subMemTypeCount["Platinum"]:0);
```

This is basically checking if it is defined or not, If defined -> prints, else 0